# import mediaplayer command does not work in android studio

Tags: android

I am new to android studio and when I try to run the command to import the media player it is not recognized and with streamlining is set it will delete any time I enter in command to import mediaplayer in the java code page. Its like I don't have the media player installed in android studio.   I have been at it for 2 days and I don;t know what the problem is and I don't see anyone with the same issue when I google.  Can anyone tell me what may be wrong or how to configure android studio?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
```

Comment: Unfortunately Android Studio still wont allow me to add import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer; into the java page. as soon as I enter the code it autimatically gets deleted.  I'm sure it has something to do with the way Android Studio is set up but I downloaded every single option there was in SDK Manager.  Anyone know why I dont have access to mediaplayer?